# Why sometime i can´t get data via using $.getJSON function?

Tags: jquery, json, get, null, getjson

I´m working Youtube API now, and sometime `data is null` , i dont know why...

```
function get_youtube_info(youtubeID) {
    $.getJSON("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/"+youtubeID+"?v=2&prettyprint=true&alt=jsonc", function(json){
            if (json.data.accessControl.embed == "allowed") {
                //do something...
            }
    });
}
```

May i use `$.ajax` , `$.get` , `$.post` or what ?

Comment: The $.getJSON call is correct and as you said it works sometimes. Iam not sure where the problem is but if this is related to youtube api I would check if the data is null and if it is try again...

Comment: are you calling the function in loop? may be the api is restricting your requests

Comment: If the YouTube API is returning null then there may be nothing you can do about it.  Your code is correct so you should get the same result every time, unless there's a problem that's out of your control.

Comment: Have you tried attaching fiddler or something to see what the response actually is from youtube?

Comment: `GET http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/hYoQH5uYv34?v=2&prettyprint=true&alt=jsonc
 
304 Not Modified
  246ms`

Comment: lol its work when i add some param like `http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/"+youtubeID+"?v=2&prettyprint=true&alt=jsonc&xxxxxxx`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sounds like youtube is expecting you to cache your response, hence the `304` try

```
$.ajax({
 url:'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/'+youtubeID+'?v=2&prettyprint=true&alt=jsonc',
 cache:false,
 dataType:'json',
 type:'GET',
 success: function(json){
            if (json.data.accessControl.embed == "allowed") {
            //do something...
        }
        if (json.data.accessControl.embed == "denied") {
            alert("not allow to embed");
          }
    },
 error: function() {alert("not found video");}
});
```

Comment: i missed `,` after `dataType:'json'` :P

Answer (score 0):

```
function get_youtube_info(youtubeID) {
    $.getJSON("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/"+youtubeID+"?v=2&prettyprint=true&alt=jsonc&myversion="+Math.floor(Math.random()*1000000)+"",function(json){
            if (json.data.accessControl.embed == "allowed") {
                //do something...
            }
            if (json.data.accessControl.embed == "denied") {
        alert("not allow to embed");
        }
    }).error(function(json) {
        alert("not found video");
    });
}
```

Now i will use like this, Add some random number to new param to get json data like "allowed" or "denied" to embed

Comment: why? All your doing here is bypassing the caching by adding a random value to the connection string? It makes much more sense to explicitly turn caching off? also getJSON does exactly as my example, its just a wrapper for the $.ajax?

Comment: i want to use 3 statements 1.`json.data.accessControl.embed == "allowed"` 2.`json.data.accessControl.embed == "denied"` and 3.`.error(function(){});`

Comment: also what happens if your random number returns the same value as it has before, which could happen, then the problem reappears,

Comment: 999999 numbers when return the same one so i will give up hahaha :D

Comment: Ok, your choice but the answer above is a hack to prevent caching, but you can just prevent caching so why hack it?